# Should I save firebase token myself or it will be auto done when registering for remote notifications?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have a chat app with firebase backend. I want to use firebase cloud functions to see if there is new write in messages so that I can then generate push notification to that device but I am confused about tokens.

Do I have to save tokens every time new user signs up or the token automatically goes to firebase once we use registerForRemoteNotifications.

Also suggest me if you have a better and clear way doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save it yourself.

The tokens are automatically generated, but saving them to a specific location, such as the server is the developer's responsibility.

If you are using Firebase database, then you could just save it to a `pushTokens` node, making sure that it can only be accessed by the corresponding users, through Firebase Rules.

Comment: I was trying to use pushkit and voip notifications on ios 10 but i see that it's not supported. Can you please tell me what methods are available so i receive push notifications in background even? Are FCM cloud functions okay for this?

Comment: Hi Jacob. AFAIK, iOS' default behavior is to disable notifications not in foreground.